# Php working with mysql and CMS

Tags: php

I am new with learning CMS. I have a project that I am doing I have half of it done but not the code part yet,just the Html part. I was hoping that maybe some might be able to help me out to understand what is being ask. I am suppose to  allow the user to edit the page title, meta description, meta keywords, page heading, subtitle, and content. I know how to connect to the database. I have tried to google a few things on CMS but nothing with only two pages alot of the videos have like 4 and 5 pages. I have to3.    Create an admin page that will update the database. This is what my admin page looks like right now. When a user puts words in those spots it is suppose to go over to the index part and change to what they wrote there.

On the index i have it  set up and the parts that need to be editable.Then once you click on say the title it will take you over to the admin for you to input your own title. Would I use something like this :

```
return <<< ADMIN_FORM

    <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="post">
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input name="title" id="title" type="text" maxlength="150" />
      <label for="bodytext">Body Text:</label>
      <textarea name="bodytext" id="bodytext"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Create This Entry!" />
    </form>

ADMIN_FORM;
  }
```

but change out the titles and thing plus add more to get everything for the linktest and pageHeading,etc or would I use something else. I am sure I know what to use but when I was told to do CMS and have never ever did a page with CMS i am over confused. Thanks for looking any information even webaddress or video would help to.

Have fixed this and got my answer thanks.

Comment: When did CMS become a language? And where can I learn it?

Comment: Thats why I am asking I dont nothing about CMS I am just being told I have to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read some beginners tutorials , like:

http://css-tricks.com/1907-php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/